# How to browse an specified folder on (from) a server through FILEUPLOAD control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I want to browse a specific folder which is on another server (other than on which our application is deployed) Through file upload control in **asp.net (C#)**.

I'll need to make a restriction on `file upload` control, that it should take every user(student) to his own profile folder. Is there any possibility or a way to get that done.

I have googled a lot, but could not get solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generaly no you can't do that. although some browser might use the value in the attribute Value.
But then again you have to know the path to their profile. So the answer is no.

Comment: Yes i will be providing it the correct path for every student profile folder from backend. Is there no way to give it path from back end to browse that particular folder?

Comment: It might work in opera browsers, by setting the value to for example value="c:\temp\" but in Internet Explorer it does not work and shouldnt work because of security issues.

Comment: Sorry there is nothing like "value" in fileupload control neither in front end attributes nor in back end.
Thanks by the way.

Comment: there is in <input type="file" > wich is the html element the fileupoload is using , you can add value attribute with addattribute method

Comment: Oh! Yes its there in HTML control.And its 'value' attibute may be working in opera, as i don't have installed opera. But it's useless for me as its not working 
in rest of browsers, i have tried it. Thanks